# How to set global variable laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I tried to make a global variable in laravel, in my code when the json return response, the data appears, but the other method is why it is null,

there is my code

```
class VendorController extends Controller
{

    private $vendor_id;

    public function index(){
    if($cek =='available')
    {
        $this->vendor_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'vendor_id' => $this->vendor_id
        ]);
    }
    }
    public function cek(){
    dd($this->vendor_id)
    }


}
```

when in function cek $this->vendor_id result is null, but in index function return->response()->json() there data is 13

Comment: Post the code showing how you're calling these methods

Comment: just only <a href =" {{route('trivendor')}}">

Comment: But how are you triggering the `cek()` method?

Comment: yes in web. php 
Route::get('/tryId', 'VendorController@cek')->name('trivendor');

Comment: And how are you triggering the `index()` method?

Comment: Use Laravel Session https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session or redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's different controller's instance. So you set the `vendor_id` in your index action, it will not display in show action,

Try to use `session` or `redis` to store the `vendor_id`:

### Session:

```php
public function index(){
    ...
    $vendor_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    $request->session()->put('vendor_id', $vendor_id);
    ...
}

public function show () {
   $vendor_id = $request->session()->get('vendor_id'); // get your vendor_id
   ...
}
```

### Redis:

PS: You need to install redis in your server.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
public function index(){
    ...
    $vendor_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    Redis::set('vendor_id', $vendor_id);
    ...
}
public function show () {
    ...
    $vendor_id = Redis::get('vendor_id');
}
```

Comment: This is correct, perhaps you should give a code example? Otherwise, this may just better off being a comment.

Comment: @GBWDev wait a minute

Answer (score 0):

**This is right way:-> Please Follow this**

```
class VendorController extends Controller
{
    private $vendor_id;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->vendor_id=DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();
    }
    public function show(){
        dd($this->vendor_id);
    }
}
```